# Restructure / rearange list

Tags: python, list

I have a list in Python which looks like this:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
```

Now I need to restructure the list in order to make it look like this:

```
data_new = [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
```

I managed to solve the problem by using two for loops:

```
data = [[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]

len_data = len(data)
len_dat = len(data[0])
data_new = []

for index_dat in xrange(len_dat):
    dat = []
    for index_data in xrange(len_data):
        dat.append(data[index_data][index_dat])
    data_new.append(dat)

print data_new
```

What is the easiest / most pythonic way of doing this? Performance is not an issue in my case but it is always nice to have good performance. Would be good to have one solution for sorting in place and onother one by making a new list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `zip`:

```
>>> zip(*data)
[(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30)]
```

If you really need the result to be a list of lists (instead of a list of tuples), you can do:

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(*data)]
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
```

Comment: `map(list, zip(*data))`